# How does Twitter's App Graph feature work?

Tags: ios, twitter

Twitter recently announced [App Graph](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172069-what-is-app-graph-on-twitter), a feature they will use to "deliver tailored content that you might be interested in." My question, though, is how they are doing this on a technical level? Is there something in the iOS SDK that enables this? Are they somehow examining a list of running process on the phone? Are they trying a bunch of custom URL schemes to see if they work? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the iOS SDK that allows you to grab information about other apps on device but this library, iHasApp, does something similar to what Twitter is doing and it uses iTunes search and AppIds:

https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp

The library grabs all app URLs with an iTunes search and compares with current appIds on device. You can read the creator of the library's blog to see exactly whats happening behind the scenes:

http://danielamitay.com/blog/2011/2/16/how-to-detect-installed-ios-apps